# find html tag and also its character position

Tags: c++, html

I was looking for a C/C++ library with a function that would allow you to search for a tag by name and attributes, and then return other attributes of the found tag, and most importantly, indicate which visible character position the tag occurred at.

Does jquery/javascript already allow this, and if so, do I just need something to process jquery/jscript from within C/C++, or is there in fact some native C/C++ library that's faster.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: Are you asking for a library to use in a C++ program? Otherwise you need to pick a language...

Comment: Georg, I don't understand your question

Comment: You are asking for a C/C++ library; but while you can use C libraries with C++, C++ libraries can't be used with C.

Comment: It would be used from within C++. I don't need/want a C++ object framework to accomplish this necessarily, just a functional API would be fine, you know something like, find_tag(char* htmlText, char* tag_name, char* attr_name, int* char_pos_out ...);

Comment: Ok, C++ it is. What do you mean with *"visible character position"*? The position the element is rendered at?

Comment: in your last comment rthe character 'C' is at position 4.

Comment: I'm processing a flash htmlText element, which has only a subset of tags, and doesn't have things like tables and so forth - so I just want the visible character position at which a tag occurs. This would be trivial except for characters expressed like '&#x102;'

Comment: So basically the character position of a tag is the count of all previous characters in the html that are not within tags and where characters expressed with & are properly counted. Could have nearly written something by now myself - except it might exclude something I'm not aware of.  As I said previously whatever is standard for running javscript from within say visual C++ would probably suffice, I'm guessing.

Comment: That visibility is not trivial to decide considering CSS, browser rendering differences, etc. If you think you know how to do it with JavaScript, you could go with an embedded IE using `IWebBrowser2` and scripting via `IHTMLDocument` et al.

Comment: Somehow what I'm saying I think has eluded you - let me repeat: What I'm calling the "character position" of a tag is the number of all previous alphanumeric characters in the html that are not within tags, and where characters expressed with '&' are properly parsed (e.g. &#x118; etc)  I'm not actually using CSS for this (though not seeing the relevance here if I were: CSS deals with presentation, not content) but thanks for the reference to IWebBrowser2 and IHTMLDocument.

Comment: When I say "not within tags" that would exclude the <body> or <html> tags, and  those tags are not even in used for this application anway.  This was harder to explain than I thought it would be.

Comment: Now i get you. Note that this confusion came completely from the use of the ambiguous term *"visible"* (which sounds like talking about presentation).

Answer (score 2):

[Tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) 
>
[XML Parser](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) 
>
XPath
>
Attribute retrieval.

That's how I'd do it. That makes the most sense and gives you the most powerful parsing.

Comment: what will it do with plain html (with <br> and so forth)

Comment: And as I said the visible character position at which a tag occurs is paramount for me as well, i.e. the count of previous alphanumeric characters not within tags and where characters starting with & are properly parsed.

Comment: @Mark: It turns <br> into <br />.

Comment: @Mark: Tagsoup makes your HTML XML-parseable, which gives you greater power in extracting information from your document. I have used Tagsoup with XML parsers to much success in screen-scraping like this.

Comment: tagsoup - OK I'll have a look.

Comment: Will not be able to fully evaluate tagsoup, etc. as I decided I didn't need to do what was I describing anyway.